# PIL Image.fromarray reducing the size of my image when saved

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

my code:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('this.jpg') # 2.72mb image 

arrayA = np.array(img)

new_img = Image.fromarray(arrayA)

new_img.save("this_changed.jpg") # to 660 kb image size
```

Comment: Please click [edit] then select your code with the mouse and click `{}` in the formatting toolbar beside **Bold** and *Italic* to format correctly as code.

Comment: Why do you think it's caused by `Image.fromaray()`? Try `img.save('this_changed.jpg')`

Comment: `.jpg` is a compressed format. The image size depends on the compression level used. PILs compression makes the files smaller and does not store there additional information which might be stored along with the image data. To copy the image you have to copy it as copy of the image file as there a many other reasons why the by PIL saved image could be not the same size as the original.

Comment: Generally notice that in absolutely most cases if you don't exactly know how things work if you found a 'bug' in a Python module or method the actual bug is in the way of how you think the outcome should be.

Comment: Helpful could be to try to answer for yourself the question: *What makes you think that the size of the saved PIL image should be exactly the same as the size of the original loaded one?*

Answer (score 1):

`PIL` will compress and subsample your image in order to save space. Try to deactivate compressing and subsamling:

```py
new_image.save("this_changed.jpg",
                quality=100, # preserve color and image quality
                subsampling=0 # use the whole image as base for the save
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**PIL** saves images with a quality of 75 by default, i.e. if you don't say otherwise. If the original image has a quality of 100, and you save it as per your code, it will save it with quality 75 which will result in a smaller file size.

Let's make an example. Here is an image with quality 100:

[image]

Let's check its quality and file size with `exiftool`:

```
exiftool -filesize -JPEGQualityEstimate -n image.jpg
File Size                       : 896738
JPEG Quality Estimate           : 100
```

Run your code, and you'll get:

```
exiftool -filesize -JPEGQualityEstimate -n result.jpg
File Size                       : 184922
JPEG Quality Estimate           : 75
```

Notice it is lower quality and smaller.

---

Now tell **PIL** to keep the quality of the original:

```
im.save('result.jpg', quality='keep')
```

and check again:

```
exiftool -filesize -JPEGQualityEstimate -n result.jpg
File Size                       : 1261893
JPEG Quality Estimate           : 100
```

Notice the quality setting has been retained and the file is now much larger - we'll come to that in a minute.

---

Just for completeness, let's tell **PIL** to use a quality of 85%:

```
im.save('result.jpg', quality=85)
```

and check results:

```
exiftool -filesize -JPEGQualityEstimate -n result.jpg
File Size                       : 232407
JPEG Quality Estimate           : 85
```

---

The next question is why the file size is different from the original when specifying `'keep'`. That is because JPEG is lossy and different encoders are allowed to make different decisions about how they do chroma-subsampling, what quantisation tables they use, whether they use integer or floating point accuracy and so on to optimise either filesize, or encoding speed or some other factor that was important to the author of the encoder. As such, you might find different Python/C++ packages produce different absolute values for pixels and different file sizes and in fact, these can change from one release/version of a library to the next. If you want your image data to remain identical, you should consider using PNG or another lossless format, e.g. NetPBM, TIFF.